# Android Kotlin Mvp Class delegation

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have the following scenario:

```
  class NowActivity: AppCompatActivity(), NowScreen, NowDelegate by NowDelegateImpl(){

  onCreate(...){
       presenter.attachView(this)
  }
```

Is there any way I can delegate the implementation of some `NowScreen` methods to NowDelegate so I can do the following inside the presenter:

```
view.callSomeFunc()
```

in which callSomeFund() is implemented in `NowDelegate`.

Is there any way of accomplish something like this? the problem is that I'm using MVP, which attach a view to a presenter. But some of the view implementation is repeated in several activities, so I would want to delegate it to another class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delegate both interfaces to the same object if it implements both interfaces.  To do so just make the object a constructor parameter, for example:

```
class NowActivity(delegate: NowDelegateImpl): AppCompatActivity(), 
                        NowScreen by delegate, 
                        NowDelegate by delegate {
   constructor (): this(NowDelegateImpl()) {}  // need this default constructor for Android to call
... 
}
```

If the delegate does not implement everything of both interfaces, you can make it a member and manually delegate some subset of the functions to it.

```
class NowActivity(private val delegate: NowDelegateImpl): 
                       AppCompatActivity(), 
                       NowScreen,
                       NowDelegate by delegate {
   constructor (): this(NowDelegateImpl()) {}  // need this default constructor for Android to call
   override fun callSomeFund() { delegate.callSomeFund() }
}
```

Both options need you to create a default constructor that creates the object used for delegation and passes that to the primary constructor.

Here it is broken out to an all inclusive sample that isn't so Android specific in case others want to see all that is going on...

**Example 1, delegate all interfaces to same object:**

```
interface CommonStuff {
    fun foo1()
    fun foo2()
}

interface LessCommonStuff {
    fun bar()
}

class CommonDelegate1: CommonStuff, LessCommonStuff {
    override fun foo1() {}
    override fun foo2() {}
    override fun bar() {}
}

class Activity1(delegate: CommonDelegate1): 
                          LessCommonStuff by delegate,
                          CommonStuff by delegate {
   constructor (): this(CommonDelegate1()) {}  // need this default constructor
   // ...
}
```

**Example 2, manually delegate some interfaces using a member:**

```
interface CommonStuff {
    fun foo1()
    fun foo2()
}

interface LessCommonStuff {
    fun bar()
}

class CommonDelegate2: CommonStuff {
    override fun foo1() {}
    override fun foo2() {}
    fun barLikeThing() {}
}

class Activity2(private val delegate: CommonDelegate2): 
                     LessCommonStuff,
                     CommonStuff by delegate {
    constructor (): this(CommonDelegate2()) {}  // need this default constructor
    override fun bar() { delegate.barLikeThing() }
}
```

Comment: what about Activities not having a constructor ... can u do that?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't have a constructor, who constructs the activity?

Comment: @user3806331 ok, fixed my answer by adding default constructor that calls the other constructor